# capistrano script fails because a test-group gem is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano

I'm deploying to a staging server which is running in environment=development. My deploy script fails with the message `Could not find gem 'webmock (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.` but I cannot see why the script should ever need that gem because my Gemfile only lists it in the `test` group.

Do you have any idea why my staging server is trying to require webmock during deployment?

**My deploy script**

Here is the command from my deploy script fails:

`executing ["cd /var/www/clu2/staging/releases/20130429170940 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab staging --set environment=development --roles db"]`

One command earlier, the script runs `bundle install`, omitting the `test` gems:

`executing ["cd /var/www/clu2/staging/current && bundle install  --without=test --no-update-sources"]`

**My usage of webmock is only in test**

You can see that webmock is only required in my spec_helper file:

```
$ grep -r webmock .
./Gemfile:  gem "webmock"
./Gemfile.lock:    webmock (1.11.0)
./Gemfile.lock:  webmock
./spec/spec_helper.rb:  require "webmock/rspec"
```

You can see that webmock is specified as a test gem in my Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'spork-rails' # pre-load rails environment for faster test launches
  gem "webmock"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly set `:bundle_without` config option in your staging deployment configuration file (do you use it? If not take a look at `capistrano-ext` gem which provides multistage features):

```
set :bundle_without, []
```

That's because `:bundle_without` is defined like this in production deployment:

```
set :bundle_without, [ :development, :test ]
```

One more thing.

I think that you should run your stage machine with production env. Staging machine is commonly used to emulate how code is working in production.